# Filter or mark a block

Tags: linux, string

I have a text with message:

`[:DNS-Google
    G1
    G2
    G3
    N1
    N2
    N3
]`

[:VD-Share
    S1
    S2
    S3
    F1
    F2
    F3
]

I need to grep block, eg: when I grep **AAA-Google**, the output will be:

`G1
G2
G3
N1
N2
N3`

This will be the same when I grep VD-Share

Filter the contents of block!

Comment: If you `grep` your provided example input for `AAA-Google`, you will not get any results as that string is not in the provided data set.  What you ask is impossible.

Comment: is `AAA` supposed to match "3 alphabet characters"?

Answer (score 1):

This will get you most of the way there:

```
awk -v pattern='\\[:...-Google' '
    $1 == "]" {p = 0} 
    p {print}
    $1 ~ pattern {p = 1} 
' file
```

You just need to figure out how to put a variable into the `-v pattern="XYZ"` part.